# How to send two variables when using respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some ajax that uses the following action.

```
  def game_type
    if params[:game_type] == "team"
      @game_for = "Team"
      @match_partial = "team_match_fields.html.erb"
    else
      @game_for = "Player"
      @match_partial = "player_match_fields.html.erb"
    end  

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { @game_for }
    end
  end
```

If I use just one variable in the `respond_to` block, things are fine, but I want to be able to pass both `@game_for` and `@match_partial` to my js file.  How can I do that?  I haven't found a good explanation of syntax for using `respond_to`.

Comment: all your instance variables are available in your js template by default. No need to pass then in

Comment: Cheers, @Vimsha - If you want to make an answer I'll check it as you were first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the instance variables are available in the template by default. No need to pass it explicitly.

With just the following code, you should be able to access both `@game_for` and `@match_partial` in your js template.

```
def game_type
    if params[:game_type] == "team"
      @game_for = "Team"
      @match_partial = "team_match_fields.html.erb"
    else
      @game_for = "Player"
      @match_partial = "player_match_fields.html.erb"
    end  

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to pass any variable to your format.js block. Whichever condition is satisfied those particular variables are set and are accessible in your .js.erb file

just mention `format.js` that's it